# replace plain urls with links having the text truncated

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using the answers from this question [How to replace plain URLs with links?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37684/how-to-replace-plain-urls-with-links) but I want the links to be truncated. For example, if the link is longer than 25 characters, I want to show [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37684/how-to-replace-plain-urls-with-links)

How can I call a slice or substring on a result from a regex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
myString.replace(/(?=http://.....)(\S{,25})\S*/g, '<a href="$0">$1</a>');
```

Though this won't show the elipsis